# UWP Storyboard not executing animation correctly

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a small button that should adjust vertically and horizontally. I Would like to use Storyboard and manipulate the X and Y under transform.

And I would like to do it code-behind.

The button moves to the correct position, but no animation is active.

```
private void AnimatePlayerMovement(Player player)
{
    //This will hold hour animation
    Piece.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    //New storyboard
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

    //New DoubleAnimation - Y
    DoubleAnimation translateYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    translateYAnimation.From = this.Path[player.from, 1];
    translateYAnimation.To = this.Path[player.to, 1];

    translateYAnimation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase();
    translateYAnimation.EasingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;

    translateYAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(translateYAnimation, Piece);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, 
           "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

    storyboard.Children.Add(translateYAnimation);

    //New DoubleAnimation - X 
    DoubleAnimation translateXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    translateXAnimation.From = this.Path[player.from, 0];
    translateXAnimation.To = this.Path[player.to, 0];
    translateXAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(translateXAnimation, Piece);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateXAnimation,
          "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");

    storyboard.Children.Add(translateXAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin();

}
```

And the button in xaml

```
<Button x:Name="Piece" Height="50" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="115,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="Assets/piece.png"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: I have tried out your code exactly (except for replacing image with a simple `Rectangle`) and the animation does work. You can find my example repo on Github - https://github.com/MartinZikmund/so-55271281

Comment: Are you sure the `this.Path[player.from, 0]` and `this.Path[player.to, 0]` values are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and the animation works properly. You can find the working repo [on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/so-55271281). As the code is almost 1:1 copy of your sample, **except** I hardcoded the `From` and `To` property values of the animations. Thus I think the problem you are seeing is that `this.Path[player.from, 0]` and `this.Path[player.to, 0]` values are the same (or very similar). This way the button jumps to the `this.Path[player.from, 0]` location and stays there, not moving further.